# Count the number of occurences of a string in response data

Tags: jmeter

I want to search a string from a response in jmeter and count the number of occurences based on which  i want to use a if controller to run the next requests. I am stuck with the code for counting the occurences

Comment: _I am stuck with the code for_ Where is that code?

Comment: @bub stuck means i could not get any code...and i am not very comfortable in java

Comment: Ok, sorry but SO is not a free coding service and your question is offtopic for SO. Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: var str1 = prev.getResponeMessage();

int matches = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(str1,"Allergy Visit Display" );
vars.put("ItemNameVar_matchNr", String.valueOf(matches));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in at least 2 ways:

1. Using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

   - Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the request.
   - Configure it as follows:

     - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `count`
     - Regular Expression: string you want to count, i.e. `JMeter`
     - Template: `$1$`
     - Match No: `-1`

   The number of matches will be stored in `${count_matchNr}` JMeter Variable

   [image: Count Matches Regex]
2. Using [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor)

   - Add Beanshell PostProcessor as a child of the request
   - Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area

     ```
     import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

     String response = new String(data);
     int count = StringUtils.countMatches(response, "JMeter");

     log.info("Found " + count + " \"JMeter\" words at the " + prev.getUrlAsString() + " URL");
     vars.put("count", String.valueOf(count));
     ```

   You'll be able to refer the matches count as `${count}` JMeter Variable

   [image: Count matches - Beanshell]

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)