# How to get number of matched elements in Extractor(Json/css/xpath)

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, extractor

As you cans see, it is a JSON extractor element in JMeter and we can find BookName elements. 
Question is, how to find total matched elements?

[image]

Comment: See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573591/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-response-data) post. I think that is what you need :

Answer (score 1):

You can find the total matched pattern using below variable:

```
${variableName_matchNr}
```

Where, variableName is the name of created variables. For this example `${BookName_matchNr}` will give you the total matched count.

Make sure to use Match No as -1 [to get all the matched counts].

[image]